# Sum of Vue Component Subtotals

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add up the subtotals in my Vue app.

Each component has its own subtotal based on user input. These then need to be added into another input outside of the components.

I keep getting stuck on how to best reference the component subtotals outside of the components. Would this best be done by adding a computed property to the #app?

```
<div id="app">
    <h1 style="padding: 2em 0 1em">Vue.JS Loop 2</h1>
    <div class="total">
        <input :value="form.income" @change="updateIncome" type="number" class="form-control" name="income" id="income" placeholder="Income">
        <!--Add all subtotals here-->
        <input :value="form.expenses" @change="updateExpenses" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="expenses" id="expenses" placeholder="Expenses">
        <hr/>
        <input v-model="form.dispIncome" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="dispIncome" id="dispIncome" placeholder="Disposable Income">
    </div>
    <div class="budget-container">
        <div class="budget" v-for="budget in budgets">
            {{budget}} Expenses
            <budget-line></budget-line>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var budgetLine = Vue.extend({
        template: `
            <div>
                <p id="result"><strong>Total:</strong> $ {{ totalQty }} </p>
            <div class="row" v-for="item in items">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Item"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="How much?" v-model="item.qty"></input>
                <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                <button @click="removeItem">-</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        `,

        data: function() {
            return { items: [] };
        },

        computed: {
            totalQty() {
                return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
                    return total + Number(item.qty);
                }, 0);
            },
        },

        methods: {
            addItem() {
                this.items.push({
                    qty: 0
                });
            }, 
            removeItem(item) {
                this.items.pop(item);
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.addItem()
        }
    });

    var budgetApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            budgets: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 
            form: {
                income: 0,
                expenses: 0,
                dispIncome: 0
            }
        }, 
        components: {
            'budget-line': budgetLine
        }, 
        methods: {
            updateIncome(event) {
                this.form.income = event.target.value
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            },
            updateExpenses(event) {
                this.form.expenses = event.target.value
                this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: you want to share the `totalQty` to its parent component?

Comment: I want to sum the totalQtys of the three budgets in the form.expenses input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is modified code which displays form expenses as total of multi line expenses you add under each budget section:

Added combination of watch and computed to achieve this. Below is high level summary of changes made:

- In `budgetLine` component added a watcher to emit changes on `totalQty`
- In `budgetApp` component modified budgets data to an object, added computed `budgetKeys` to render section name, added `calculateExpense` method that will be called on emit from budgetLine to update budgets and watcher on budgets to update the `form.expenses`

```js
var budgetLine = Vue.extend({
  template: `
            <div>
                <p id="result"><strong>Total:</strong> $ {{ totalQty }} </p>
            <div class="row" v-for="item in items">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Item"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="How much?" v-model="item.qty"></input>
                <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                <button @click="removeItem">-</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        `,

  data: function() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    totalQty(value) {
      this.$emit('update-expense', value)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalQty() {
      return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + Number(item.qty);
      }, 0);
    },
  },

  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.items.push({
        qty: 0
      });
    },
    removeItem(item) {
      this.items.pop(item);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.addItem()
  }
});

var budgetApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    budgets: {
      'One': 0,
      'Two': 0,
      'Three': 0
    },
    form: {
      income: 0,
      expenses: 0,
      dispIncome: 0
    }
  },
  components: {
    'budget-line': budgetLine
  },
  watch: {
    budgets: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.form.expenses = this.budgetKeys.reduce((accum, key) => accum + this.budgets[key], 0)
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    budgetKeys() {
      return Object.keys(this.budgets)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateIncome(event) {
      this.form.income = event.target.value
      this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
    },
    updateExpenses(event) {
      this.form.expenses = event.target.value
      this.form.dispIncome = this.form.income - this.form.expenses
    },
    calculateExpense(amount, budget) {
      this.budgets[budget] = amount;
      console.log(this.budgets)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 style="padding: 2em 0 1em">Vue.JS Loop 2</h1>
  <div class="total">
    <input :value="form.income" @change="updateIncome" type="number" class="form-control" name="income" id="income" placeholder="Income">
    <!--Add all subtotals here-->
    <input :value="form.expenses" @change="updateExpenses" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="expenses" id="expenses" placeholder="Expenses">
    <hr/>
    <input v-model="form.dispIncome" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="dispIncome" id="dispIncome" placeholder="Disposable Income">
  </div>
  <div class="budget-container">
    <div class="budget" v-for="budget in budgetKeys">
      {{budget}} Expenses
      <budget-line v-on:update-expense="calculateExpense($event, budget)"></budget-line>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```